Fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 crashes right before language selection - White screen of death - "Something has gone wrong"
I'm on an Acer Nitro N50-650 with 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700F, a NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 4060 and a 1TB SSD, trying to freshly install brand new Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 Noble Numbat. This is a multi monitor setup with four monitors.
I've downloaded the image from Ubuntu website and created a USB Stick from it, like I did it already hundreds of times before with other versions and distributions.
When booting the USB Stick, the boot menu comes up, then I choose "try or install"... then the boot logo comes up and after some time waiting, when the installer should start, I get a white screen of death saying "Oh No" Something has gone wrong". This happens even before the language selection.
When then waiting some seconds, the screen becomes black, the installer loads with the language selection, but I can not do anything. No keyboard, no mouse, no reaction at all.
No dual boot setup or something else special. Just a simple fresh install - no upgrade - onto a formatted 1Tb SSD.
Am I alone with that problem? I can noit find any other reports of this specific behaviour...
I already have tried it several times, with several usb sticks and also downloaded the images several times. When using another image, for example Ubuntu Desktopn 23.10, everything works as expected.
Best regards
Christin

... I found indication that the latest two versions of the nVidia driver are causing trouble. Try find a way to enable the nouveau driver at bootup.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1468088/289138

Well, okay... after many tries with many different usb-sticks, I followed the little hint from @Hannu in the comments and that gave me an idea:
I've now tried to boot the Ubuntu 24.04 usb-stick with "safe graphics" from the boot menu. This has worked like a charm.
Even though that I have started the install with safe graphics, it has installed the newest Nvidia kernel modules and 3D and everything is working now.
So, problem is solved.

I would mark this as the accepted answer, but I need to wait two days until I can do that.

The actual driver installed is of interest: 545 and 550 are still having problems when using the standard installers (ubuntu-drivers, Software&Updates) with the standard repositories. See launchpad bug 2037004.and add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list in the upper left corner.
